# ¿Cómo leer texto entre diferentes líneas y guardarlo en nuevos documentos de texto?

Tags: python

mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un archivo de texto que tiene la forma que se ve más abajo, lo que quiero hacer es tomar todo el texto que esté entre las líneas "78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 'XXZ' 'DÍA' Apr 1973" y guardarlas en nuevos documentos de texto, esto considerando que todas las líneas "78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 'XXZ' 'DÍA' Apr 1973" cambian después del "at" por 00z ó 12z y luego cambia el día dependiendo del mes.

```
78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 00Z 01 Apr 1973

1013.0    11   22.2   21.2     94  15.92     60     4   294.3  339.9  297.9
1000.0   119   22.0   20.5     91  15.43     45     9   295.1  339.6  297.9
978.9    304   21.6   19.4     87  14.67     30     12  296.6  339.1  299.2
976.0    329   21.6   19.2     86  14.56     30     12  296.8  339.0  299.4
944.6    609   19.9   17.9     89  13.90     35      7  297.8  338.3  300.3
911.5    914   18.0   16.6     92  13.20     40      4  298.9  337.6  301.3
 Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 295.25
          Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 15.85
          1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5751.00
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 42.50



78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 12Z 01 Apr 1973
640.0   3877    5.6   -8.4     36   3.19                316.7  327.3  317.3
623.0   4097    5.8  -10.2     31   2.84                319.3  328.9  319.9
456.0   6579   -8.3  -22.3     31   1.41                331.5  336.6  331.8
400.0   7574  -18.9  -33.9     25   0.55                330.3  332.4  330.4
264.0  10532  -40.1  -49.1     38   0.17                341.0  341.7  341.0
222.0  11690  -48.7                                     345.1         345.1
    Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 295.25
          Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 15.85
          1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5731.60
Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 50.29

78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 00Z 02 Apr 1973
1012.0     11   22.0   21.3     96  16.03                294.1  340.1  297.0
1000.0    117   22.8   22.8    100  17.83                295.9  347.4  299.1
 979.3    304   22.6   22.0     96  17.30     45     11  297.6  347.9  300.6
 975.0    343   22.6   21.8     95  17.19     46     11  297.9  347.9  301.0
946.0    609   21.2   20.1     94  15.95     50     13  299.1  345.7  301.9
913.7    914   19.6   18.2     92  14.61     55     12  300.4  343.4  303.0
 882.6   1219   17.9   16.3     90  13.37     65      4  301.7  341.3  304.1

78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 12Z 02 Apr 1973

  500.0   5850   -4.7  -26.7     16   0.87    345     25  327.2  330.5  327.4
  400.0   7570  -16.9  -36.9     16   0.41    315     25  332.9  334.6  333.0
  300.0   9660  -33.3  -47.3     23   0.18    290     30  338.3  339.1  338.4
   267.0  10466  -40.1  -51.1     30   0.13    287     39  339.9  340.4  339.9

                        Showalter index: 5.26
                           Lifted index: 3.52
```

Actualmente estoy usando esto:

```
f = open("archivo.txt")
content = f.read()
txtStart = "78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 00Z 01 Apr 1973"
txtEnd = "78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at 12Z 01 Apr 1973"
text = content.split(txtStart)[1].split(txtEnd)[0].strip()
final_file = open("archivo2.txt", "w")
final_file.write(text)
```

Pero lo anterior sólo me funciona para el texto indicado, quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar indicándome como hacer un for que me ayude a recorrer las líneas variando el "XXZ" y el "día"

Espero haberme dado a entender y me puedan ayudar, agradezco de antemano toda ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: ¿La idea sería que cada bloque que empieza por una linea  `78897 TFFR Le Raizet...` y que  termina cuando otra linea como esta es encontrada termine en un txt diferente? ¿Esas lineas son exactamente iguales hasta el `at` a lo largo de todo el fichero? Puedes usar una expresión regular con [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) o leer el fichero linea a linea si quieres preservar memoria comprobando si la linea cumple el patrón y cambiando el fichero de salida cuando esto ocurra.

Comment: Exactamente lo que preguntás es justo lo que necesito. Con el re.split no hay necesidad de usar ciclos ni nada por el estilo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es detectar secuencialmente cuando comienza una sección según un patrón de expresión regular y separar cada línea leída a continuación en una lista asociada a esa sección, luego, el proceso se repite al detectar un nuevo cambio de sección. Veamos como podría ser:

```
import re
import pprint

patron = "78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at ([0-9a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{4})"

clave = None
secciones = {}
with open("archivo.txt") as f:
  for linea in f:
    m = re.match(patron,linea)
    if m:
      clave = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}". format(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4))
      secciones[clave] = []
    else:
      if clave:
        secciones[clave].append(linea.strip())
```

- En primer lugar definimos un patrón de búsqueda como este `78897 TFFR Le Raizet, Guadeloupe Observations at ([0-9a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{4})` que básicamente indica un texto fijo y `([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})` hasta 3 caracteres alfanuméricos, espacio, `([0-9]{2})` dos caracteres numéricos, espacio, `([a-zA-Z]{3})` hasta 3 caracteres alfabéticos, espacio y `([0-9]{4})`cuatro caracteres numéricos. Esto además es un patrón de captura, los datos variables serán "capturados" y podremos usarlos posteriormente.
- Usamos la construcción `with open("archivo.txt") as f:` con esto nos aseguramos cerrar el archivo al salir del bloque de código. En tu código faltaba cerrar explícitamente el archivo.
- Luego mediante `for linea in f:` iteramos línea a línea.
- Con `m = re.match(patron,linea)` verificamos la línea con el patrón definido, si coincidieran `m` sería un objeto y no `None` en cuyo caso definimos la clave para un diccionario con los 4 datos capturados , el `at` y las partes de la fecha. Luego simplemente agregaremos una nuevo ítem al diccionario `secciones` para esta clave e iremos agregando cada una de las líneas leídas hasta que encontremos una nueva sección o el fin del archivo.
- Lo importante que al finalizar deberíamos tener un diccionario cuyas claves serían algo así: `00Z-01-Apr-1973` y el valor de las mismas serían las líneas que le corresponden.

En caso de querer ver todo, y usando `pprint` que mejora las visualización de objetos compuestos obtendríamos algo así (en función de tu ejemplo):

```
pprint.pprint(secciones)

{'00Z-01-Apr-1973': ['',
                     '1013.0    11   22.2   21.2     94  15.92     60     4   294.3  339.9  297.9',
                     '1000.0   119   22.0   20.5     91  15.43     45     9   295.1  339.6  297.9',
                     '978.9    304   21.6   19.4     87  14.67     30     12  296.6  339.1  299.2',
                     '976.0    329   21.6   19.2     86  14.56     30     12  296.8  339.0  299.4',
                     '944.6    609   19.9   17.9     89  13.90     35      7  297.8  338.3  300.3',
                     '911.5    914   18.0   16.6     92  13.20     40      4  298.9  337.6  301.3',
                     'Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 295.25',
                     'Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 15.85',
                     '1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5751.00',
                     'Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 42.50',
                     '',
                     '',
                     ''],
 '00Z-02-Apr-1973': ['1012.0     11   22.0   21.3     96  16.03                294.1  340.1  297.0',
                     '1000.0    117   22.8   22.8    100  17.83                295.9  347.4  299.1',
                     '979.3    304   22.6   22.0     96  17.30     45     11  297.6  347.9  300.6',
                     '975.0    343   22.6   21.8     95  17.19     46     11  297.9  347.9  301.0',
                     '946.0    609   21.2   20.1     94  15.95     50     13  299.1  345.7  301.9',
                     '913.7    914   19.6   18.2     92  14.61     55     12  300.4  343.4  303.0',
                     '882.6   1219   17.9   16.3     90  13.37     65      4  301.7  341.3  304.1',
                     ''],
 '12Z-01-Apr-1973': ['640.0   3877    5.6   -8.4     36   3.19                316.7  327.3  317.3',
                     '623.0   4097    5.8  -10.2     31   2.84                319.3  328.9  319.9',
                     '456.0   6579   -8.3  -22.3     31   1.41                331.5  336.6  331.8',
                     '400.0   7574  -18.9  -33.9     25   0.55                330.3  332.4  330.4',
                     '264.0  10532  -40.1  -49.1     38   0.17                341.0  341.7  341.0',
                     '222.0  11690  -48.7                                     345.1         345.1',
                     'Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 295.25',
                     'Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 15.85',
                     '1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5731.60',
                     'Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 50.29',
                     ''],
 '12Z-02-Apr-1973': ['',
                     '500.0   5850   -4.7  -26.7     16   0.87    345     25  327.2  330.5  327.4',
                     '400.0   7570  -16.9  -36.9     16   0.41    315     25  332.9  334.6  333.0',
                     '300.0   9660  -33.3  -47.3     23   0.18    290     30  338.3  339.1  338.4',
                     '267.0  10466  -40.1  -51.1     30   0.13    287     39  339.9  340.4  339.9',
                     '',
                     'Showalter index: 5.26']}
```

Por último, para ver todas las secciones capturadas podrías hacer:

```
for seccion in secciones:
  print(seccion)

00Z-01-Apr-1973
00Z-02-Apr-1973
12Z-01-Apr-1973
12Z-02-Apr-1973
```

Si quieres ver las líneas de una en particular:

```
print("\n".join(secciones["12Z-02-Apr-1973"]))

500.0   5850   -4.7  -26.7     16   0.87    345     25  327.2  330.5  327.4
400.0   7570  -16.9  -36.9     16   0.41    315     25  332.9  334.6  333.0
300.0   9660  -33.3  -47.3     23   0.18    290     30  338.3  339.1  338.4
267.0  10466  -40.1  -51.1     30   0.13    287     39  339.9  340.4  339.9

Showalter index: 5.26
```

O, si quieres imprimir todas:

```
for seccion in secciones:
  print("\n".join(secciones[seccion]))
```

Nota: Esta forma secuencial de leer el archivo, es más acorde con archivos de gran tamaño ya que no requiere cargarlos completamente en memoria.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho, muchas gracias por toda la explicación.